# If width of parent element is less than 500px set children width to auto?

Tags: css, less

I have some spans laid out inside of div whose width is set to 100%, each span has styling on it to give it 500px width.

So like this:

```
<div>
<span style="width=500px">child span</span><span style="width=500px">child span</span><span style="width=500px">child span</span><span style="width=500px">child span</span>
</div>
```

When the width of the parent div goes below 1000px I'd like the spans to now have their width set to 100%

```
<div>
<span style="width=parent.Width < 1000px ? auto : 500px">child span</span><span style="width=parent.Width < 1000px ? 100%: 500px">child span</span><span style="width=parent.Width < 1000px ? 100% : 500px">child span</span><span style="width=parent.Width < 1000px ? 100% : 500px">child span</span><span style="width=parent.Width < 1000px ? 100% : 500px">child span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I can only imagine this working if your parent `div.width == window.width` because then you can use a media query.

Comment: @Zze is there another way to do it? using something like flexbox?

Comment: try using @media queries

Comment: Can you explain exactly how should the spans arrange, column wise or row wise with the `parent div` size

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/07/how-i-ended-up-with-element-queries-and-how-you-can-use-them-today/, https://elementqueries.com/, https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid red;/*remove this. it is only for visualisation*/
}

div span {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>child span</span><span>child span</span><span>child span</span><span>child span</span></div>
```

Try resizing the editor to see the results. And remove inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make use of @media(max-width) here. And remember span width by default is auto. So you need to add display styling too.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
}

@media(max-width:1000px) {
  span {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>child span</span>
  <span>child span</span>
  <span>child span</span>
  <span>child span</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try media queries!

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>child span</span>
  <span>child span</span>
  <span>child span</span>
  <span>child span</span>
</div>
```